# How to match Linux parent directories with Java Regex?

Tags: java, regex

Linux path is `../../test/test/mydirectory/.....`

I tried to remove all the `../` with this regex

`[s{/././///}]`

But this removes all special characters

I only want to remove `../../../../../` and leave the real path

```
String result = path.replaceAll("[s{/././///}]","");
```

I expect the regex to identify all possible `../../../../` empty parent directories and leave only the real directory where the real path name starts

**start only where the letters start**

Comment: `.` is a special regex character. If you want to treat `.` as a normal character, you have to escape it.

Comment: You probably want `s.replaceFirst("^(?:\\.{2}/)+", "")`

Comment: Yes thank you so much. It works great

Comment: Do you actually want to use the regex though? Why not `java.nio.file.Path`?

Comment: because it comes as a string and not a Path object. I'll have to typecast and catch the typecast exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
s.replaceFirst("^(?:\\.{2}/)+", "")
```

The pattern matches

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:\\.{2}/)+` - one or more repetitions of:

  - `\.{2}` - two dots
  - `/`  - slash.

The `.replaceFirst` will find the first occurrence of the pattern and will replace it with an empty string.